# Is apache a server

Tags: java, apache

I am very new to servlets. I have gathered some information about them, please tell me where I am wrong. Apache is a server that will run on the server machine basically its an application. Our java Servlets will also reside on the server machine and will interact with this server. Basically apache is only for accepting the request, if it contains the web page demanded in the URL it sends it back to the client by creating a socket. If it doesn't contain the web page it interacts with our Servlet application which will give it the web page in html and it will further send it back to the client. Interaction of the apache server with the java servlet is completely hidden from us. All our java servlets will be contained in the container which is tomcat.

Comment: APACHE is web server, check apache.org

Comment: *"Apache httpd" is a web server

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apache Web Server - is a server written in C which handles the HTTP protocol and serves normal web content such as HTML pages, images etc. It also supports various plugins for dynamic content such as Server Side Includes, PHP and connecting to Servlet Containers. In itself it is NOT a servlet container.

Apache Tomcat - is also a web server, written in Java. It is specifically designed for Servlets, but also serves HTML and images. In the past it was a bit slower than the native Apache Web Server (due to JVM overheads and servlet-oriented design) and thus in certain architectures you would have an Apache Web Server serving normal static content (HTML, Javascript, Images etc.) and have a handler which connects to Tomcat for dynamic servlet-generated content. It might still be the preferred architecture for high scalability requirements, but sometimes this makes things more complicated too, so its debatable.

Both are maintained by Apache, the same open source foundation. There are other web servers (nginx for example) and also servlet containers (Jetty for example).

Answer (score 4):

There's the Apache Foundation, the Apache Project, Apache License and various project under the umbrella of Apache.

The most famous project/product is Apache httpd, the webserver, often just named "Apache", but you can summarize all of the other components under that name as well.

"Apache Tomcat" is a servlet container / application server, that you can use to host java web applications.

"Apache httpd" is commonly used as the frontend webserver, that communicates with "Apache tomcat", either through a component named mod_proxy or mod_jk (maybe others as well)

Or, in other words, I have no clue what you're asking, but maybe this helps identifying the different items with the same (or similar) name.

Disclaimer: I might use the different names incorrectly as well...

Answer (score 1):

For some people, including me, usually, apache means apache httpd when we talk about web servers.
You are correct for some certain scenarios.
Apache is server which is good at handling static pages and tmocat is server which is good at generating dynamic pages(such as servlets as you mentioned). Either of them can be used independently. They can be also used together, just as you mentioned, with apache handling static pages and tomact handling servlet. And mod_jk is the module providing the bridge between apache and tomcat.

Answer (score 1):

No. Apache is a free software foundation. Apache HTTPD is a server.

Answer (score 0):

Ohh no, You can find more about this on Google. Normally Apache is open source product development fundation. They have large amount of open source projects.

You should refer these

http://www.apache.org/

http://www.apache-da.com/products

Comment: I think this should be a comment.